# condition to use GLSurfaceView on android

Tags: java, android

I use `GLSurfaceView` but occur `NullpointerException`

I want showing camera preview to use `GLSurfaceview`

I must use `GLSurfaceView`

recently , occur nullpointerException code

MainActivity.class

```
public class CameraMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   private GLSurfaceView glview;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       .
       .
       .
       glview = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.framelayoout_network);
       VideoRendererGui.setView(glview, null) ;
   }
```

(VideoRendererGui is `webRtc`library

VideoRendererGui.class

```
public class VideoRendererGui implements Renderer {
     private static VideoRendererGui instance = null;
     private static Runnable eglContextReady = null;

     public static void setView(GLSurfaceView surface, Runnable eglContextReadyCallback) {
    instance = new VideoRendererGui(surface);
    eglContextReady = eglContextReadyCallback;
}
```

and activity_main.xml

```
  <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/framelayout_network">
    </android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>
```

logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(GLSurfaceView.java:523)
      at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
      at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:232)
      at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8004)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1233)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know why occur NullpointerException

perhaps, use `GLSurfaceView`need condition?

please advice for me

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoRendererGui.setView(glview, null) ;
```

should be change to,

```
VideoRendererGui.setView(glview, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "log something what you want...");
        }) ;
```